# How to create a border (camera type) with 3 colors?

Tags: html, css, colors, border

I want to create a border (camera type) with 3 colors (blue, white and red).

I created this HTML code:

```
<div class="reinsurance-offer">
    <div class="reinsurance-offer-link"><a href="/node/133" hreflang="fr">Faites la promotion de vos événements</a></div>
</div>
```

I applied this CSS:

```
#block-subtheme-olivero-views-block-reassurance-block-1 .reinsurance-offer {
    background-color: #f7f9fa;
    padding-right: 2.25rem;
    padding-left: 2.25rem;
    padding-top: 1.6875rem;
    padding-bottom: 1.6875rem;
    text-align: center;
}

#block-subtheme-olivero-views-block-reassurance-block-1 .reinsurance-offer-link {
    display: inline-flex;
    padding: 0.75rem;
    border: 5px solid;
    border-color: #E20E17 #1F71B8;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Here is the rendering :

[image]

I want to make the same display as in the image below, without the blur effect.

How can I do this in CSS and is it possible?

[image]

I didn't manage to get the desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not really sure where you want to use this, but what about something like this:

```css
.link {
  --link-border-width: 5px;
  color: grey;
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
  display: block;
  padding: .5rem 1rem 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.link::before,
.link::after {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  border: 4px solid red;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.link::before {
  border: var(--link-border-width) solid blue;
  border-right: none;
  left: 0;
}

.link::after {
  border: var(--link-border-width) solid red;
  border-left: none;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="link">This is my link<a>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted. Does this CSS work with all mobile and desktop browsers?

Comment: @Mathieu i think so, but the best way to be sure is to test it. You can also add all needed vendor prefixed here: https://autoprefixer.github.io/ (you can even choose for which browser versions you want to add prefixes

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need a lot of code. One gradient can do the job:

```css
.box {
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 10px solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(90deg,red 33%,#0000 0 66%,blue 0) 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```